# JavaScript - Pdf Generation / Print Ok, Now how I want Download document as a PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf, download

I have a simple code that perfectly works for html to pdf print. Now I want to download document as a pdf file.

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" data-print/>

<div data-print-content>
    <h1>Scan and Pay</h1>
</div>
```

```
//Print a Div
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.printDiv = function () {
        var printContents = $(this).html();
        var originalContents = $('body').html();
        $('body').html(printContents);
        $('body').addClass('js-print');
        window.print();
        $('body').html(originalContents);
        $('body').removeClass('js-print');
    };

    // Print
    $('[data-print]').on('click', function () {
        // $('[data-print]').click(function() {
        $('[data-print-content]').printDiv();
    });
});
```

Live demo:
https://codepen.io/salahuddin/full/KKmNawY

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting it to pdf. You are just printing it!
If you have a pdf printer service, you get the pdf. But your page just prints a HTML page.

If you want create a pdf over your page, you need to create a pdf. For example with the jspdf library:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF